# finding nth root of a number by using divide and conquer method

Tags: c++, algorithm, divide-and-conquer, cmath

I need help on how to get nth root of some number.

User enters number n and number he wants root of. I need to solve this without cmath lib and with divide and conquer method.

Here's my code that doesn't work yet:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

float pow(float a,float c){
    if (a == 0)
        return 0;
    else if(a == 1)
        return 1;
    else{
        float p = pow(a,(c/2));
        if(c%2)
            return p*p*a;
        else
            return p*p;
    }
}

int main(){
    float a,b;
    float c;
    cout << "Enter positive number:(base)" << endl;
    do{
        cin >> a;
    }while (a < 0);
    cout << "Enter number: (root)" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    c = 1/b;
    cout << "Result:"<<pow(a,c) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas on how to approach this problem would be more than useful.

Comment: The line with `c%2` should not compile.

Answer (score 8):

Let me tell you how you can use divide and conquer for finding square root. The nth root would be similar.

For a given number `x`, you need to search for it's square root between `0` and `x`. Divide it by `2` = `x2`. If the `x2 * x2` < `x` then your search space moves to `x2 -> x` or else it will be `0 -> x2`. If `x2 * x2` matches `x` then your square root is `x2`. Similar technique for nth root.

Comment: If the exponent is negative, it goes the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

For those not doing numerical experiments: use the `<cmath>` functions `sqrt` and `cbrt` (cube-root) to construct the any root that is factorable by 2 and 3.  For example, the 4th root is `sqrt(sqrt(x))` and the 6th root is `sqrt(cbrt(x))`.  If you need something for general use you can construct a recursive function which calls `sqrt` and `cbrt` appropriately.

I'm guessing this will give a faster and more accurate answer than `pow`, if that matters.  If it doesn't, just use `pow`.

Comment: sqrt(cbrt(x)) will give 6th root, as the exponents multiply. this is no way to get uneven exponent roots

Comment: @transistor argh, that was a dumb mistake (fixed).  Of course 2x3 = 6.  Thanks!  But I should also point out 3x3=9.  :)